# How to get Open Table Restaurant ID(rid) from Google Places API Webservice search result?

Tags: json, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

[image]

Above image is the screen shot of search result I got from Google Maps Restaurant search, the **Find table** link will redirect me to URL: http://www.opentable.com/jojo?rid=4871 .

Here the URL contains Table Restaurant id **rid=4871**, Now my question is how do I  get that restaurant ID from Google Places API Webservice? Which i need to pass it on to the URL: [http://www.opentable.com/jojo?rid=_MY_ID] later.

place_id for that location is **placeid=ChIJI9k11O5YwokRJXZKb8r3CoQ**
and I can query the same using this: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJI9k11O5YwokRJXZKb8r3CoQ&key=AIzaSyA_CiSjKrULed0y4gGkJiRrh6QnvJEgaSU

but the JSON returns does not contain any Restaurant ID's(rid).

Comment: I don't think the Google Places API has any method to return you OpenTable IDs, even though Google use them on their own results.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @HSWarraich No :(